# How to fetch NSString from a JSON array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is my JSON:

```
-elements: [
    {
    HomeworkElementSession: {
        id: "608743",
        name: "Interval for x",
        description: "",
         }
    }
]
...
```

I was able to get to the point where I have an actual NSArray representing the "elements" node and therefore containing only one object in the array.
But I have no idea how to reach this string "name".

What i did was:

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"elements"];
            for(int i=0; i<elements.count; i++){
                NSDictionary* homeworkSession = [elements objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* name = [homeworkSession objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSLog(@"%@",name);
            }
```

But i get nil in Log.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"elements"];
for(int i=0; i<elements.count; i++){
       NSDictionary* homeworkSession = [elements objectAtIndex:i];
       NSDictionary* dataDict = [homeworkSession objectForKey:@"HomeworkElementSession"];
       NSString* name = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
       NSLog(@"%@",name);
 }
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Another pair of not so tired eyes :)
Thanks, mate!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Dictionary for key HomeworkElementSession first

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"elements"];
            for(int i=0; i<elements.count; i++){
                NSDictionary* mainhomeworkSession = [elements objectAtIndex:i];
                NSDictionary* homeworkSession = [mainhomeworkSession objectForKey:@"HomeworkElementSession"];
                NSString* name = [homeworkSession objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSLog(@"%@",name);
            }
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *elements = [singleHomework objectForKey:@"elements"];
for(NSDictionary *dict in elements){

       NSDictionary* dataDict = [dict objectForKey:@"HomeworkElementSession"];
       NSString* name = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
       NSLog(@"%@",name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be help full , 
Note: you are getting output in NSString so use this

```
 NSString *singleHomework = @"your data";
NSMutableDictionary *dataDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[singleHomework dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:Nil];
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [dataDic valueForKey:@"elements"];
NSLog(@"Name Print %@",[dataArray[0] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you have a hyphen in the dictionary key "-elements".  That could be a problem.  However, your main problem is that your JSON is an array containing a single dictionary which then contains a dictionary (HomeworkElementSession) which has attributes.

```
NSString * json = @"{\"elements\": [{\"HomeworkElementSession\": {\"id\": \"608743\", \"name\":\"Interval for x\", \"description\": \"\"}}]}";
NSData * jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *e;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&e];
NSLog(@"dict=%@", dict);
```